# Getting user data is inconsistent on the php and javascript sdk

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-fql, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-iframe

I've been developing a facebook application that uses a combination of the php sdk and the javascript sdk. It runs in a tabbed iframe on facebook and is hosted on my own server. I'm using the latest php and javascript sdk files as of now (Sept 06, 2011, 2:50PM). The first inconsistency is in the php sdk when getting the user id. This is my code:

```
require 'fb_php_sdk/facebook.php';

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => $app_id,
    'secret' => $app_secret,
    'cookie' => true
));

$user = $facebook->getUser();
if ($user) {
    $permissions_granted = true;
} else {
    $permissions_granted = false;
}
```

This very frequently returns '0' as the facebook ID, no idea why. Though almost as frequently returns the actual facebook id.

The other issue is with images. I often get images not showing up when calling this url:

```
<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/' . $uid. '/picture/" />
```

When I use fql I inconsistently get 'undefined' as a result when performing this query:

```
FB.api(
    {
        method: 'fql.query',
        query: 'SELECT name,pic FROM user WHERE uid=<? echo $user ?>'
    },
        function(response)
        {
            alert(response[0].pic);
        }
);
```

I really don't understand what would cause this inconsistency and it's making bug testing very difficult. If anyone has experienced this kind of behaviour and can point me in the right direction I'd really appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: @Nick I've already looked through here for a few weeks now. I've googled and read through tons of documentation. But thanks

Answer (score 0):

> This very frequently returns '0' as the facebook ID, no idea why. Though almost as frequently returns the actual facebook id.

Of course, because your app needs at least the default permissions. Otherwise you'll get nothing about the user. And same with your images. I bet most time your $uid contains the number zero.

Did you check what facebook returns? It should be something like:

> {
>      "error": {
>         "type": "OAuthException",
>         "message": "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user."
>      }
>   }

So you need to get permissions of the user to get access to his/her data.

Kind regards,
Jurik